# Can a Sonicwall NSA 2400 failover to a Pro 2040?

Tags: firewall, sonicwall

If my sonicwall NSA 2400 was to ever die I want it to automatically failover to the old PRO 2040 it replaced. Is this possible with two different generations of Sonicwall? If so, what things do I need to take into consideration? My Google-fu fails me so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For a failover scenario, the two devices should be of the same model and running identical firmware. Also, the two devices are to be registered with Sonicwall as a Failover pair.

Comment: If you have an L3 switch on the LAN side of things that is capable of resolving a next-hop gateway, then you could have it change it's default route based upon a path validation rule.